# Add reference to a downloaded dll in Visual studio and resolve in Github

Tags: c#, visual-studio, github

I have a visual studio solution which is synced on GitHub. I want to add a few dlls to one of the project. I downloaded those dlls on to my desktop, then right click on project and added those using "Add Reference->Browse". Then I pushed on to the repository.
But when my friend fetched the changes from the repository, it shows the reference, but says "could not resolve reference"? How do I make sure that the dlls actually get pushed to the repository and not just the path.

Comment: You generally shouldn't include compiled code in your checked in source code. Is this a DLL that you have the source code for? Then either add that project to the solution, or turn it into a NuGet package and create a package server to pull it from, that way you can properly version it.

Answer (score 6):

Add a folder to the project, add the dlls, reference from the new folder, and commit the folder to github.

Or, if the dlls are available as nuget packages you could install them through nuget and make sure the "packages" folder is committed with the project in github.

As Metro Smurf pointed out, you could also omit the nuget packages folder and use the package restore option. Here's a link to the nuget documentation on this option: [Package Restore](http://docs.nuget.org/Consume/Package-Restore)

Comment: Don't commit the packages folder; just the nuget config. When the next dev picks up the solution, the packages will be restored.

Comment: I think you have to have the package restore option enabled for the project for this to work, right?

Comment: That's correct, but not needed when including just the nuget config in the commit; the setting is a VS setting (that can be included in the commit) and will simply read from the config file to pull in the assemblies when the project is built.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. Thanks!